# Clicking a button that's set to hide in xcode leaves a thin line in the simulator before hiding

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to swift so struggling a little bit to figure out what's going on. Here's a snippet of my code. I've also attached pictures showing how it looks after I click the button. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnOptionOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnOptionTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnOptionThree: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    frontLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    backLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0

    btnOptionOne.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    btnOptionOne.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    btnOptionOne.layer.borderWidth = 3.0

    btnOptionTwo.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    btnOptionTwo.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    btnOptionTwo.layer.borderWidth = 3.0

    btnOptionThree.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    btnOptionThree.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    btnOptionThree.layer.borderWidth = 3.0

    card.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
    frontLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
    backLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0

    card.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    frontLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    backLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

    frontLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    backLabel.clipsToBounds = true
}


@IBAction func didTapOnFlashcard(_ sender: Any) {
    if frontLabel.isHidden == true{
        frontLabel.isHidden = false;
    }
    else{
        frontLabel.isHidden = true;
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapOptionOne(_ sender: Any) {
    btnOptionOne.isHidden = true
}
```

[Before clicking on the first option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtUZn.png)

[After clicking on the first option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUQ5v.png)

Answer (score 1):

While clicking remove the shadow:-

```
btnOptionOne.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
btnOptionOne.layer.shadowRadius = 0
btnOptionOne.layer.shadowColor = nil
```

Comment: I tried adding your code in didTapOptionOne function and still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Also, I'm not setting any shadows to my option buttons. Does that make any difference? Or do I need to add the above code if I'm not setting any shadows?

Comment: @nikeshparajuli what is the `frontLabel `? Is this label inside the button or what?

Comment: If you go to this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtUZn.png the label showing the question is my frontLabel.